# Сравнение использования связного списка в C и JAVA

Tags: java, c, list

Хотелось бы подробнее понять разницу выполнения разных задач связного списка в двух диаметрально противоположных языках : `c` и `java`.

Конкретнее: сравнить и найти отличия в добавлении и удалении элемента в связной список/из связного списка.

И дело не в коде (он у меня имеется), а в технике применения.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Возьмем пример кода на с:

```
void deleteCar(char* reg) {

    struct LinearNode *current, *previous;
    bool found = false;

    if (isEmpty())
        printf("Error - there are no nodes in the list\n");
    else {
        printf("**************Sell car:**************\n");
        current = previous = front;

        while (!found && current != NULL) {
            //check by comparing if registration number exists and car is reserved
            if ((strcmp(reg, current->element->registration) == 0) && (current->element->reserved == true)) {
                found = true;
            }
            else { //go to the next node
                previous = current;
                current = current->next;
            }//end else
        } //end while

        if (!found)
            printf("Error - there is not such car with registration number %s or this car is not reserved\n", reg);
        else { //if found
            if (current == front) {
                front = front->next;
                free(current); //remove node from list
            } //end else
            else {
                previous->next = current->next;
                free(current);//remove node from list
            } //end else
            printf("Car with registration number %s has been deleted\n", reg);
        }//end else
    }//end else
}// end deleteNode
```

и вот метод для удаления элемент на джаве:

```
public boolean delete(T element){

    LinearNode<T> previous = list; 
    LinearNode<T> current = list;
    boolean found = false;

    while (!found && current != null)
    {
        if (current.getElement ().equals (element)) {
            found = true;
        }
        else {
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
    }
    //found loop
    if (found)//we fount the element
    {

        if(current == this.list){

        this.list.getElement();
        this.list = this.list.getNext();
       }

       else
           if(current == this.last){

        previous.setNext (null);
        this.last = previous;
        }
           else{
               previous.setNext(current.getNext());
               current.setNext (null);
           }
    this.count--;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Можно ли после этих примеров сказать, что в java можно использовать код, который будет `generic`, в отличии от `c`?

Comment: По каким критериям сравнивать собираетесь?

Comment: например в `с` использует `pointers`, а `java` - `references`. но по всей видимости, это одно и тоже) вот я и пытаюсь найти главные различия. и главные критерии тоже пытаюсь найти, чтобы разобраться на что обратить внимание

Comment: @Alex и указатель, и ссылка указывают на следующий элемент списка, да. Если покажете примеры кода - можно ещё искать отличия. Так-то и на С, и на Джаве можно по-раному написать, и отличия будут разные

Comment: Спасибо, обновила пост, задала еще один вопрос

Comment: @Alex а кстати, код отлажен и протестирован? Работает?

Comment: да, все работает

Comment: @Alex нашёл отличие: код на С находит и удаляет элемент, а код на Java удаляет первый элемент

Comment: А для С можете посмотреть на [нормальную](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h)  реализацию списков.

Comment: @Schulz, да, вы правильно подметили, есть и тот, который удаляет не только первый элемент) спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @avp, а что значит нормальную? у меня неправильно выполнено?

Comment: Наверное правильно, но по учебному. Лучше (раз уж представилась такая возможность) ознакомить с тем, как на самом деле надо их делать, а уже потом заниматься сравнительным анализом. Кстати, разница между Си и Java не столь уж разительна, как ее принято преподносить.

Comment: @avp, спасибо! обязательно изучу!

Comment: @avp вот кстати спорный вопрос. Да, в Линуксе нормальная реализация. Но так ли необходимо начинающему знать все детали реализации (и все обёртки)? Не будет ли достаточно для обучения знать, что бывают списки, в них возможны такие-то операции за такую-то сложность, реализованы примерно так, чтобы в случае необходимости можно было применить готовый список, написать, или отладить?

Comment: @Schullz, я не преподаватель, а практик, и считаю, что если детали начинающему  программисту мешают, т.е. если  он не способен на основе изучения чужих деталей и собственных попыток их использовать научиться вырабатывать эффективные абстракции, то может ему лучше заняться чем-то другим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В плане реализации самописного связного списка Java и C практически не отличаются, принцип одинаковый. Создаётся класс или структура элемента списка, в ней какая-то информация и ссылка на следующий элемент. В C указатель со 'звёздочкой', в Java без неё. Можно просто перечислить все различия синтаксиса языков.